# Google Play Store error code -2

Tags: android, google-play

I need to sort this out because it's a pretty big problem. My users keep sending emails that they can't install the app because an error code: -2. Here's a screenshot I received.

Do you have any advice? Thanks a lot!

[image]

**UPDATE:** Looks like after an app update the problem got solved. Users reporting install now works.

Comment: Funny I've never heard of Error code: -2 in Google Play. I'm interested to hear about this as well.

Comment: So it seems like it can be downloaded, but right after it starts to show "Installing..." this dialog appears.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807091/android-app-not-installaing-from-playstore-on-kitkat

Comment: Hi Alex Newman I'm also living the same problem. Did you find any solution.

Comment: Hi Alex Newman What did you do on update? any special things? thanks

Comment: @AlexNewman what changes did you do in the update that solved this issue?

Comment: Same problem for my app. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: Have just released another update. No special changes. Have you tried this out?

Comment: I have the same issue with my app. (Error code: -2) Running on 4.4.

Comment: I release another version with no special changes. Afterwards everything worked again. Does anyone know what the Error Code -2 means? I was not able to find an description of this error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not a real solution but I had the same issue days before. After several days searching in the internet I updated my app in Play Store with some minor changes (nothing that really helps to solve this error I think).

The error simply dissapeared. Maybe is just a Google Play bug. So if you are planning an update just do it and I think it will be solved.