# Android app not installaing from playstore on Kitkat

Tags: android

Our app is not getting installed on phones running on Android KitKat. However the same app is getting installed when trying to install the apk directly. It is also working fine on other android versions. It is failing with Error Code -2. Have tried all the options which is there in the google support link but didn't help.

[image: Error Message]

Manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appilyever.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <permission
        android:name="android.os.Bundle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />



    <uses-permission android:name="com.appilyever.app.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCMV925evT4ROgFFRBqGevExaX4xNdh8hg" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WebViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.appilyever.app.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.appilyever.app.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.appilyever.app.gcm.GcmIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is this happening on all KitKat phones ?

Comment: I have tried on 3 different KitKat phones and it is happening in all of them.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748485/google-play-store-error-code-2

Comment: can you show the manifest?

Comment: Hi, have added it to the post. Thanks

Comment: Hi Madhan I have android 4.4 device and installed your app without any error. Diid your updated your app or what did you do? thanks

Comment: Hi, yes we managed to fix the issue. We had to change one of the permissions in the manifest file. Changed the  previous value to this new value : <permission
        android:name="android.os.Bundle.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Answer (score 1):

As found by several people at [Google Play Store error code -2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748485/google-play-store-error-code-2), and now also by myself, a new release with an insignificant change makes the problem go away.

For future reference, the relevant line in the device log appears to be:

```
04-28 19:49:24.629: W/Finsky(19249): [11195] com.google.android.finsky.receivers.aa.a(2975): IOException while copying my.package.name (my.package.name): java.io.IOException: Output length overrun
```

After which it downloads the package file again, and then fails with:

```
04-28 19:49:45.619: A/Finsky(19249): [1] com.google.android.finsky.installer.aq.a(168): Already streaming file my.package.name682140009.apk for my.package.name
04-28 19:49:45.619: A/Finsky(19249): com.google.android.flib.log.WhatATerribleException
04-28 19:49:45.619: A/Finsky(19249):    at com.google.android.flib.log.a.e(SourceFile:107)
04-28 19:49:45.619: A/Finsky(19249):    at com.google.android.finsky.utils.FinskyLog.e(SourceFile:70)
04-28 19:49:45.619: A/Finsky(19249):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.aq.a(SourceFile:168)
04-28 19:49:45.619: A/Finsky(19249):    at com.google.android.finsky.receivers.z.onPostExecute(SourceFile:3852)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to installed your App successfully on my device running 4.4.4. Please try clearing the Google Play Store cache on the device that fails to install. The steps are **Settings -> Apps -> All -> Google Play Store -> Clear Cache**. It is also recommended to clear the cache for Google Play Services: **Settings -> Apps -> All -> Google Play Services -> Clear Cache**.
Then try to install the app again. Also let's not leave out the magical device restart - sometimes restarting the device has the effect of clearing some of these errors.
Perhaps closely related to your issue:

[Play Store won't load or download
    apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/troubleshooter/6241347?hl=en&rd=3#ts=6241336)

[Play Store App Download Issue: "Can't install
    App"..](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/play/lNZ3-nymVTU/77rSq5GFBAAJ)

Comment: Hey this is not solution for our problem. We updated our app on Play store and many users cant download app. We cant do this step for all users :(

Comment: Have you tried the suggested steps and did they not resolve the issue for at least one of the users? Can you also indicate **what changes** you have made that seem to affect some of your users? I did not see "What's New" section on your [App listing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appilyever.app).